# Refinery CMS + devise_cas_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms

I am trying to figure out how to add CAS authentication to Refinery.  The best arrangement I have found so far is to use [`devise_cas_authenticatable`](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable).

I used `rake refinery:override model=user` and replaced `:database_authenticatable`:

```
# /app/models/refinery/user.rb
if self.respond_to?(:devise)
  devise :cas_authenticatable, ...
end
```

But I can't find where to set the CAS configuration values, e.g.:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.cas_base_url = "https://cas.myorganization.com"
  ...
end
```

Does anyone know if there is an existing initializer where this belongs?  Also, any thoughts on the task of making Refinery work with CAS would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the CAS configuration values in a Rails initializer, e.g.

```
$ cat config/initializers/devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.cas_base_url = "https://cas.myorganization.com"

  # you can override these if you need to, but cas_base_url is usually enough
  # config.cas_login_url = "https://cas.myorganization.com/login"
  # config.cas_logout_url = "https://cas.myorganization.com/logout"
  # config.cas_validate_url = "https://cas.myorganization.com/serviceValidate"

  # The CAS specification allows for the passing of a follow URL to be displayed when
  # a user logs out on the CAS server. RubyCAS-Server also supports redirecting to a
  # URL via the destination param. Set either of these urls and specify either nil,
  # 'destination' or 'follow' as the logout_url_param. If the urls are blank but
  # logout_url_param is set, a default will be detected for the service.
  # config.cas_destination_url = 'https://cas.myorganization.com'
  # config.cas_follow_url = 'https://cas.myorganization.com'
  # config.cas_logout_url_param = nil

  # By default, devise_cas_authenticatable will create users.  If you would rather
  # require user records to already exist locally before they can authenticate via
  # CAS, uncomment the following line.
  # config.cas_create_user = false  
end
```